# Preserve state of View Controller when using segues

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a View Controller (A) with a text field and some other things in it.

When the user presses a button on View Controller A it segues to View Controller B using "Present Modally".

How could I preserve the state of View Controller A (e.g. text in the textfield) when returning to it from View Controller B. I would rather avoid using NSUserDefaults if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you present view controller B modally on top of view view controller A, view controller A is not closed - it's just covered by view controller B. The close action on view controller B should invoke `dismiss(animated:completion:)` to dismiss the modal. When you do that you can be certain that view controller A will be revealed with its state intact.

You should NOT use a segue to go back to view controller A. That would create a new copy of view controller A that would wind up being displayed on top of the original view controller A and the new view controller B. That is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Aha very good catch for a noob like me, 'You should NOT use a segue to go back to view controller A' that is my biggest mistake.